# Heat/gain loss through radiation (question below):

Tags: radiation

Many modern houses in colder countries are designed to conserve energy. State the colour that the outside of the house should be painted to reduce heat loss.

My initial thoughts were that the house should be painted black as black is a good absorber and emitter of heat. However, the answer is white. I did not understand how, as white is a good reflector and so would reflect all the heat that is meant to be kept in the house, thus allowing more heat loss.

I wanted to know the reason for the colour and some other applications of this (such as the colour of clothes worn on a hot day: black or white or colour of paint for a house on a sunny day).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question assumes that in winter the house is a net source of heat due to its heating system (and to a lesser extent the occupants). It will produce more heat internally than it can absorb from the outside and its walls will be hotter than the outside environment. Therefore it needs to radiate as little heat as possible.

If the paint is white it will radiate less heat outwards than if it was black. It will also absorb less heat, but there is less heat coming from outside than there is coming from the inside. (There must be, otherwise the house would not get cold in the first place).

The rules are:

- Good absorber/bad reflector = good radiator (black)
- Bad absorber/good reflector = bad radiator (white)

  [[Wikipedia]Kirchhoff's law of thermal radiation#history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_law_of_thermal_radiation#History)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but I had one question, how would white radiate less heat when it is a good reflector compared to black?

Comment: Things that reflect well radiate badly and things that reflect badly radiate well. White reflects well but radiates badly. Black reflects badly but radiates well. It has to be so. If black reflects badly that means it absorbs well. If it absorbs well it has also to radiate well, otherwise it would just get hotter and hotter.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. So, since white radiates badly, it prevents heat from escaping and so white is used? (just to ensure I have understood the concept clearly)

Comment: Yes - I think that is what the question is after.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you!